# What is the correct way to return map iterator from nested component?

Tags: reactjs

I constantly end up generating various errors when trying to return (more complex) values from my render method. Most of which, I was able to resolve. But this time, the component doesn't render at all, yet... there is no console error.

I understand the standard return(...) syntax, when it comes to returning single <div/> elements, but in some cases I don't fully understand why it should break my code.

Code examples I'm experimenting with:

```
class RenderMe1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { list: ['A','B','C'] }
    }
    render() {
        return(
        <div>
            <div>
                /* === Works === */
                { this.state.list.map((object, index) => this.state.list[index] ) }
            </div>
        </div>);
    }
}

class RenderMe2 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { list: ['0','0','0'] }
    }
    render() {
        return(
        <div>
            <div>
                /* === Doesn't Work === */
                { this.state.list.map((object, index) => { this.state.list[index] } ) }
            </div>
        </div>);
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<RenderMe1 />, document.getElementById("root"));  // works
ReactDOM.render(<RenderMe2 />, document.getElementById("root2")); // doesn't work
```

For practice purposes, I'm using in-browser babel plugin, hence the JSX syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code inside brackets still works simply because while JavaScript *calculates* the statement, but it doesn't return it.

In this particular case, the issue is with the arrow function itself, though. There is a specific rule arrows follow: when {} brackets are skipped, the statement *is* in fact treated as a return value, without having to use return keyword. This cleans the code a bit. But soon as you add the {} brackets, whatever is inside must be explicitly returned using the return keyword. The following will fix your issue:

```
{ this.state.list.map((object, index) => { return(this.state.list[index]) } ) }
```

Remember, React is still really just JavaScript (often ES6+.) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Your first example is an implicit return. meaning, you don't need to specify the return keyword because you haven't used curly braces and as such it returns the expression

The second one you have so it isnt returning anything. Here's the amended code

```
class RenderMe2 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { list: ['0','0','0'] }
    }
    render() {
        return(
        <div>
            <div>

                { this.state.list.map((object, index) => { return this.state.list[index] } ) }
            </div>
        </div>);
    }
}
```

I assume you're doing it this way because its an example but you could just do

`this.state.list.map(listItem => listItem);`

Answer (score 1):

The reason the second approach doesn't work is a syntactice subtlty with arrow functions.

When you wrap an arrow function that contains a single statement with { and }, then that arrow function is effecitvly equivilant to returning `undefined`.

So for instance:

```
(object, index) => { this.state.list[index] }
```

is equvilant to:

```
function(object, index) { 

   this.state.list[index];

   // Notice that nothing is returned
}
```

Conversly, by excluding the `{` and `}`, as you are doing in the working version:

```
{ this.state.list.map((object, index) => this.state.list[index] ) }
```

that is effectivly equaivlant to doing:

```
{ this.state.list.map(function(object, index) {

   // The function is returning something
   return this.state.list[index]
}
```

This `return` behaviour that "comes for free" with the non `{ .. }` arrow functions, is the reason the first version works, and the latter version fails. For more information, [see this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Returning_object_literals)